# Can I put Framer.js prototype in the App Store?

Tags: javascript, ios, framerjs

Bit of a weird question here...

I'm looking to build an iOS app art project that's mostly pieces of UI moving around the page.

I could achieve what I'm after in Framer very quickly, which got me wondering, is it possible to port a Framer.js prototype into a native web app (or phone gap/cordova).

My gut feeling is no. But thought it'd be worth asking to see if anyone knows it's possible or has seen it before.

Thanks

Comment: yes, codova is just a browser without the address bar. basically...

Answer (score -2):

Although I'm not sure about iOS, I think it could be feasible for desktop. I've recently stumbled upon NW.js, previously known as Node-webkit. It enables you to create a standalone executable using web technologies.

It works on OSX, Windows and Linux. It has somewhat an easy learning curve. I've achieved some basic results from a Framer project under one hour.

Here, you can have a look!
http://nwjs.io

Good luck with your projects.

Philippe